# XCOPY multiple from input file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, input, xcopy

Can anyone help me making a batch file copying folders with content to another folder where both the source folder and the target folder is given from a source file.
Ex:

```
\\server1\folder1 \\server3\folder1 /E /C /I /Q /G /H /R /K /Y /Z /J
\\server1\folder2 \\server3\folder2 /E /C /I /Q /G /H /R /K /Y /Z /J
\\server2\folder1 \\server3\folder3 /E /C /I /Q /G /H /R /K /Y /Z /J
\\server2\folder9 \\server3\folder4 /E /C /I /Q /G /H /R /K /Y /Z /J
...
```

I guess I need to use the FOR command, but need help with the syntax.
How should the input file containing source and destinaton look like?

Comment: UNC path usually start with two slashes \\.  So you could just make a delimited file with source,destination and have a `FOR /F` command to read that file.  I would suggest using ROBOCOPY instead of XCOPY.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, supposing your input file is "C:\input_file.txt", run something like this to see what's going on...

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=? usebackq" %%A IN ("C:\input_file.txt") DO echo %%A
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=? usebackq" %%A IN ("C:\input_file.txt") DO xcopy %%A
pause
```

At the end of the day you just need this though...

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=? usebackq" %%A IN ("C:\input_file.txt") DO xcopy %%A
```

Explanation...

Documentation on [For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) loop and [xcopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

`For /F` loops through your input file line by line. For each line it splits the line into pieces. These pieces are called "tokens". Pieces are recognized by some character called a deliminator (delims). This is done so that you can work with individual parts of each line. However, in your case, you don't need to split your lines up. They're already formatted as arguments. So use a more obscure illegal filepath character like "?" as your deliminator. Since you can bet that it won't be there, you'll get your entire line as one token.

Setting tokens=* simply gets all tokens, but as was just stated if you only have 1 token then this could just as well be `tokens=1`.

`usebackq`is probably a good idea so that you can use quotes around your input file path to handle spaces in the path.

Then you just have a command portion of your `For /F` where you can use a command like `Echo` or `xcopy` and pass tokens as arguments. As stated earlier, you can just pass your entire line of text as a single token because it's already formatted as multiple arguments.

Also, it looks like your work system is designed to use xcopy, so maybe it's best to just stick with that, but [RoboCopy is a good alternative](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).